# How do I add km/mile markers to a leafletjs map with a gpx file?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gpx

I have managed to add a polyline from a GPX file using Leaflet.js and the leaflet-gpx plus the result is here: http://ruter.pebi.dk/#gpx=https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1818604/ruter/2016/uge%2034/tl_5.4_km.gpx

I would like to be able to display distance markers along the route - any pointers as how to go about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a plugin for that, assuming you pass the GPX file to a GeoJSON using omnivore for example.

https://github.com/adoroszlai/leaflet-distance-markers

Comment: This is actually the first plugin I found to match the KM markers I have seen in other applications. I think this will be the one that I use.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use something like [Turf.js](http://turfjs.org/docs/#along) or [cheap-ruler](https://github.com/mapbox/cheap-ruler#alongline-dist), and their `along()` functions.

These functions take a line geometry on the surface of the geoid, and a distance (usually in kilometers), and return a single latitude-longitude point.

Once you have these functions to calculate the (geodetic) length of a line and points along that line given their distance to its beginning, fetching the position of milestones becomes a trivial task. Once you have these positions in a lat-lng format, it's also trivial to display them as markers with Leaflet.

Comment: Thanks!! Looks exactly like what I need - will post back after I have had a chance to test and implement.

Comment: I have taken a given gpx file which has a track that is reported as being roughly 10 km long.

If I use turfjs to measure the length a little over 13 km is reported and cheap-ruler reports 11,7 km.

How should I interpret these measurements compared to the length reported by the GPX file?

Comment: Edit: found some articles explaining geodetic measurement.

Comment: Geodesy is hard. Making geodetic calculations is hard, and making them quickly is even harder. Check https://www.npmjs.com/package/geographiclib if you need exact measurements - but remember this still won't take into account slopes! (distance on the sea level surface is not equal to distance when going up and down hills)